# How to each message should hide in 3 sec

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use this purr in my app so when this click on regular link it's adding message box so what i want is it's maintaining some timeout so present my question is how could i set this as global because present it's showing one by one but when it's in top it's taking 3 seconds to hide so rest of all in ques so in this case i want like when i clicked on regular more times every msg it's should take 3 seconds and hide.

http://kitchen.net-perspective.com/purr-example-4.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off use the removeTimer option of the plugin to change how long it stays visible.

```
$( notice ).purr(
{
  usingTransparentPNG: true,
  removeTimer:3000 //in milliseconds before disappear
};
```

As for the rest of your question will need a bit more of an explanation on what you wish it to do :)

**UPDATE**

Above works to set the timeout of each one to 3seconds however they are in a queue behind each other if that is the issue I would try a different plugin for this like [JGrowl](http://stanlemon.net/pages/jgrowl)

Or write your own as it seems purr is designed to do that.

**Update2**

If you wrap your call to purr in a check to see if it exists you can limit it to 1 visible at a time

```
 if(!($('.notice').length > 0)) { //if it dont exist allow another to show.
     $( notice ).purr({
       usingTransparentPNG: true,
       removeTimer:1000
      });
 }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BVb9W/2/)

Comment: when click on Regular link it's showing message so i want to hide that message with in 3 sec... if i click to see 10 msgs at a time all should hide with in 3 sec.

Comment: I am trying to do like that so can you help me on this.

Comment: Post what you have n i can help further :)

Comment: hi thanks for your reply can you tell where i have to add this function

Comment: i updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BVb9W/1/) to show you, but like i said if the problem is that they are queuing behind each other then you may need to use a different plugin

Comment: is there any other way to modify using the same plugin...because i already try to use that function in my code but wont work any thing

Comment: It does work but not for your intended purpose, Are you trying to get them all to disappear at once or only allow one up at a time?